# RabbitMQ DotNet Client does not connect to SSL

Tags: .net, ssl, mono, rabbitmq, haproxy

We are trying to make a PoC showing that applications written in different languages can communicate through RabbitMQ broker in one organization. We run vanilla RabbitMQ docker image **rabbitmq:3.6.1-management** and vanilla haproxy docker image **haproxy:1.6.5** that does SSL:

```
frontend amqp_front
    bind *:5672 tcp-ut 5s
    mode tcp
    timeout client 60s
    timeout client-fin 1s
    no option clitcpka
    default_backend amqp_back

frontend amqp_front_ssl
    bind *:5671 tcp-ut 5s ssl crt /etc/certs/haproxy/rmq.pem ca-file /etc/certs/haproxy/root.crt verify required
    mode tcp
    timeout client 60s
    timeout client-fin 1s
    no option clitcpka
    acl client ssl_c_s_dn(CN) -m str cli
    tcp-request content reject if !client
    default_backend amqp_back
```

RabbitMQ config is:

```
[
  {rabbit,
    [
      { tcp_listeners, [ 5672 ] },
      { ssl_listeners, [ ] },
      {default_pass, <<"pwd">>},
      {default_user, <<"usr">>},
      {default_vhost, <<"default">>},
      {loopback_users, []}
    ]
  },
  { rabbitmq_management, [
      { listener, [
        { port, 15672 },
        { ssl, false }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
].
```

We have written a trivial code in **Go** & **Node.js**, that both load root.crt, cli.crt & cli.key and successfully connect to SSL port 5671 and consume.

Attempt to write the same trivial code in .Net, using RabbitMQ.Client.dll (version 3.6.0, 3.6.1, 3.6.2) failed though:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store (StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open (OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

var factory = new ConnectionFactory ();
factory.Ssl.Enabled = true;
factory.Ssl.ServerName = "rmq";
factory.Ssl.Certs = store.Certificates;
factory.Ssl.CertPassphrase = "";
factory.HostName = "localhost";
factory.Port = 5671;
factory.UserName = "usr";
factory.Password = "pwd";
factory.VirtualHost = "default";

var conn = factory.CreateConnection ()
```

What happens is .Net client simply ignores port 5671 disregarding the settings above, it just goes to 5672. If 5672 is open - connects to it, and if 5672 is closed - fails with connection refused.

Code in Go and Node.js prove that my SSL setup is valid. 
Error of .Net client shows that SSL stuff does not even have a chance to jump in.

I'm on debian jessie & Mono.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: How does your `rabbitmq.config` look like?

Comment: I have update the original post with RabbitMQ config. It is a default config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with the RabbitMQ .net client 3.6.2 library not respecting the specified port when using SSL.

It has since been fixed and will be available when 3.6.3 is released (they synchronize releases with the server, so have no idea when this might ship).

Your options are:-

- Use an older version of the .net client
- Build the .net client from the latest source
- Use the standard ports if you can
- Wait for 3.6.3 to be released

Answer (score 0):

I'm had a similar problem connecting to a docker rabbitmq container from masstransit Net Core Client. The following is my configuration that **works**, can be useful:

*Some notes:
Masstransit: 5.1.5, Net Core version: 2.2*

Docker-compose:

```
...
  bus_rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    hostname: docker-host
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "databus"
      RABBITMQ_SSL_CACERTFILE: "/app/certs/dev/myCA.pem"
      RABBITMQ_SSL_CERTFILE: "/app/certs/dev/rabbitmq/rabbit-server.crt"
      RABBITMQ_SSL_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT: "false"
      RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE: "/app/certs/dev/rabbitmq/rabbit-server.key"
      RABBITMQ_SSL_VERIFY: "verify_peer"
      RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SSL_CACERTFILE: "/app/certs/dev/myCA.pem"
      RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SSL_CERTFILE: "/app/certs/dev/rabbitmq/rabbit-server.crt"
      RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SSL_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT: "false"
      RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SSL_VERIFY: "verify_peer"
      RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SSL_KEYFILE: "/app/certs/dev/rabbitmq/rabbit-server.key"
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "15671:15671"
      - "5672:5672"
      - "5671:5671"
    volumes:
    - ./certs:/app/certs
    networks:
      - local_network
...
```

Client configuration:

```
...
var rabbitCredentials = CredentialsService.RetrieveRabbitMqCredentials();

builder.Register(c =>
    {
        return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.Host(rabbitCredentials.RabbitConnectionString, 5671, rabbitCredentials.RabbitVHost, h =>
            {
                var certData = CertsService.RetrieveCertificateInfo(ServiceType.RabbitMq);

                h.Username(rabbitCredentials.UserName);
                h.Password(rabbitCredentials.Password);
                h.Heartbeat(10);
                h.UseSsl(s =>
                {
                    s.Protocol = SslProtocols.Tls12;
                    s.Certificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certData.Path);
                    s.AllowPolicyErrors(SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch);
                    s.UseCertificateAsAuthenticationIdentity = false;
                });
            });

            sbc.ReceiveEndpoint("data_queue", ec =>
            {
                // loading consumers
                ec.LoadFrom(c);

                // loading saga state machines
                //ec.LoadStateMachineSagas(c);
            });
        });
    })
    .As<IBusControl>()
    .As<IPublishEndpoint>()
    .SingleInstance();
...
```

I need to use:

> AllowPolicyErrors(SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch)

to avoid server name mismatch in my certificate.